# Добавление элемента в избранное в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Пишу тестовое приложение для работы с БД используя технологию Room.

Создал адаптер для вывода данных в `RecyclerView` и смог вывести данные в него. Но не знаю как реализовать добавление элемента списка в избранное. Каждый `item` имеет кнопку `ImageButton (btnFavorites)` с иконкой, которая позволяет добавлять или удалять из избранного элемент (в БД в таблице есть поле favorites где может быть 0 или 1).

Нужно чтобы если нажали кнопку `btnFavorites` и если элемент НЕ в избранном, то он добавлялся в избранное и иконка менялась, и наоборот, если элемент был в избранном и нажали кнопку, то он удалялся из избранного и иконка менялась.

Не знаю как реализовать такое в через Room. Подскажите пожалуйста.

RoomAdapter.java

```
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.RoomViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Bludo> bludoList;
    private List<Bludo> mFilteredList;
    private Context context;
    String favorite;

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
        void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public class RoomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtDescription;
        public ImageView img;
        public Button btnFavorite;

        public RoomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
            img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            btnFavorite = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnFavorite:
                    mItemClickListener.onFavoriteButtonClick(mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
                    break;
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            }
        }
    }

    public RoomAdapter(Context context, List<Bludo> bludoList) {
        this.bludoList = bludoList;
        this.mFilteredList = bludoList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new RoomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RoomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bludo bludo = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(bludo.getName());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(bludo.getDescription());

        Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/images/" + bludo.getImage() + ".png")).into(holder.img);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = bludoList;
                } else {

                    List<Bludo> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Bludo bludo : bludoList) {

                        if (bludo.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(bludo);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Bludo>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

BludoDao.java

```
@Dao
public interface BludoDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM bludo")
    public LiveData<List<Bludo>> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM bludo WHERE id = :id")
    Maybe<Bludo> getById(long id);

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    public void insertBludo(Bludo bludo);

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RoomAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    RoomAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView rvList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        BludoDao bludoDao = (BludoDao) AppDatabase.createPersistentDatabase(getApplicationContext()).bludoDao();

        bludoDao.getAll().observe(this, (List<Bludo> bludoList) -> {
            adapter = new RoomAdapter(MainActivity.this, bludoList);
            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            rvList.setAdapter(adapter);
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        Intent secondActivity = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        secondActivity.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(secondActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "id = " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
        search(searchView);
        return true;
    }

    public void search(SearchView searchView) {

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if (adapter != null) adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AppDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {Bludo.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract BludoDao bludoDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "test.db";

    public static AppDatabase createPersistentDatabase(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Пробовал в `MainActivity` метод `onFavoriteButtonClick` сделать такой, но приложение вылетает из-за того UI поток блокирует интерфейс  вроде как

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on
>   the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period
>   of time.

**

```
@Override
public void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id) {
    bludoDao.getById(id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableMaybeObserver<Bludo>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Bludo bludo) {
                    String fav = bludo.getFavorites();
                    if (fav.equals("0")) {
                        fav = "1";
                        bludoDao.itemUpdate(id, fav);
                    } else {
                        fav = "0";
                        bludoDao.itemUpdate(id, fav);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // ...
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить поле с `favorite` (true/false) в мблицу и в объект. Если пользователь сделал объект любиым, вы меняете этому объекту поле  `favorite` и асинхронно отправляете запрос с изменением в БД.

Более корректным вариантом стало бы отправка запросов в базу после того как пользователь покидает экран. Допустим пользователь удалил несколько элементов, добавил один и два сделал `favorite`. Все эти действия можно выполнить отдельными запросами, либо одним при `destroyed` экрана:
для этого вы заводите локальное поле у всех объектов, например, `isModified`. Если объект изменен, то устанавливаете флаг. При `destroy` экрана, формируете из модифицированных объектов список и его пишете в БД. 
Такая организация будет несомненно лучше, потому как приложение будет работать быстрее и с меньшими затратами.

Comment: destroy же может и не быть, тогда данные будут утеряны

Comment: в каком случае его может не быть?

Comment: батарея села, выбрал батарею из телефона

Comment: а если во время выполнения вашего запроса я выдерну батарею, он выполниться?

Comment: во всяком случае, вы всегда можете поставить это чуть "повыше", например в onPause. Там проверять, есть ли модифицированные объекты, и если есть - сохранять их

Comment: ну какбы если записать в бд перед изменением view, то вы не успеете выбрать батарею, т.е если пользователь не увидит измененение кнопки, то для него и так будет ясно что ничего не произошло, думаю лучше всего делать асинхронный запрос в бд когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку

Comment: если записать асинхронно, то пользователь увидит вьюху раньше, чем данные окажутся в базе. А если синхронно, то ему придется кажды йраз ждать - это раздражает. К тому же, если батаерия садиться, обработчики всеравно будут выполнены. Другой вариант, если телефон окончательно умрет, но я не считаю вариант с выдергиваением батарейки актуальным. Последний  телефон со сьъемной батарей который я видел была кнопочная нокия)

Comment: но все-же вы ничего не успеете зделать за время которое нужно данным чтобы оказаться в бд, даже синхронный запрос должен быть быстрым

Comment: это дурной тон, заставлят ьпользователя ждать выполнения синхронного локаьного запроса. Где грань вы проведете грань между быстрым локальным запросом , не очень быстрым и медленным? В какой момент нужно использовать асинхронный? Приложение ваше. я всего лишь дал Вам совет

Comment: ГеоргийЧеботарев, да асинхронный запрос должен быть

Comment: грань, ну в зависимости от данных, если просто маленькие запросы то их можно выполнять асинхронно, а для больших есть кнопочка сохранить)

Comment: Без меня тут уже дискуссия пошла) В Таблице в БД есть поле favorites, только оно строковое. А Можно небольшой пример как все-таки это все реализовать? Меня интересует добавление или удаление из избранного сразу как только пользователь нажал кнопку btnFavorites.

Comment: То что в ответе словами написали понятно и так. А есть примеры как это реализовать? Я например могу при нажатии на btnFavorites получить id элемента, а потом как обновить запись в БД не совсем понятно. В вопросе обновил коды адаптера и MainActivity сделав получение ID элемента при нажатии на btnFavorite.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как обновить сам элемент

Comment: я не работал с room, но думаю у него есть документация